# Having an issue with my regex query to Mongo in Java

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

```
String searchQuery = "st";
BsonDocument regexFilter = Filters.regex("name", "^.*" + Pattern.quote(searchQuery), "i").toBsonDocument(null, null);

userQuery.putAll(regexFilter);

FindIterable<Document> allDocs = mongoCollection.find(userQuery);
```

The above is all I run currently when doing a query.

If I am looking for a substring "st" in the `name` field in mongo, I will still be finding values where the `name` field doesn't even contain the substring "st".

However, whenever I change the pattern from:

```
"^.*" + Pattern.quote(searchQuery)
```

to

```
"^" + Pattern.quote(searchQuery)
```

I will get correct results, but only if the String in the name field starts with "st", like "Stephanie". Which isn't what I want...I should also be getting names like "Justin". Currently I am getting "Nalissa" with the sample code at the very top as well which doesn't even contain st...

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/ is a very good tutorial side for using regex, give it a try.

Comment: Make a temporary string out of `"^.*" + Pattern.quote(searchQuery)` and see what it is. No need to obfuscate when debugging something.

Comment: In Perl, `\Q..\E` resolves to `\.\.` Is that how it is in Java ? Try without the `\Q\E` notation and see if it works. If it does, use a seperate regex to quote metachars, like replace `[$^.*+?\[\]\\()]` with `\\$&` or equivalent instead of the static function.

Comment: @Maxt8r yes, java is the same: `"\\Qquoted-regex\\E"` or `Pattern.quote(some-regex)` does the same thing.

Comment: @Bohemian - I believe only `\Q` is needed and that will quote to the end of the string when the regex is compiled. At least in Perl it works that way.

Comment: Did you ever find out if the `Filters.regex()` is using the Java _matches()_ function or the _find()_ function ? I looked all over but did not find any info. Is there any  source code to look through ?

Comment: @Maxt8r yes, in java too `\Q` starts quoting and omitting `\E` means it stays in effect to the end of input.

Answer (score 1):

In Java land, unlike many other languages, a `String` matches a regex if, and only if, the *entire* `String` is matched by the regex.

Add `".*"` to the end of your regex:

```
BsonDocument regexFilter = Filters
  .regex("name", ".*" + Pattern.quote(searchQuery) + ".*", "i")
  .toBsonDocument(null, null);
```

Note also that you don't need `"^"` at the start or `"$"` at the end,  because they are *implied* when having to match the entire `String`.

Comment: I believe in Java regex, the Matcher class also has a find() method as well as the matches() method.[ I've googled Mondodb querries and it seems they use different regex engines. I can't seem to find a distinct parameter definition their Filters.regex() that define how the _pattern_ parameter is to be used. They do seem to have a Find() function that takes a regex, That might use the Java find() matcher method, but I don't know. Also if using matches() with a regex that has the multiline flag the anchors don't mean BOS/EOS. And on multiline strings, the dot-all modifier should be used.